# UbuntuServer 19.04 cant access internet but SSH

Tags: networking, server, ssh, internet

I'm new with Ubuntu. I needed to install a Ubuntu-Server and connect with SSH. After many Problems it worked, but now i can't connect with the Internet.

```
sudo more /etc/resolve.conf
more stat of /etc.resolve.conf failed: no such file or directory
```

Everytime I start my Server, following message appears:

```
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
```

If I try to Ping www.google.de for example this happens:

```
sudo ping www.google.de 
ping: www.google.de: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

My Setting in /etc/network/interfaces are:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
#
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
#
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

And i can't Ping 8.8.8.8

```
sudo ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

I'm thankful for every help!

Comment: What does `more /etc/resolve.conf` show? Please edit the results of that command into the question (but do feel free to remove the comments at the top we only need the nameservers. Also edit out any personal info if there is any like your outside IP)

Comment: added. what do you mean with personal info like outside IP? Sorry english isnt my motherlanguage, so i dont know where to find it.

Comment: Eh what is with the error? The line shows a dot where i expect a dash

Comment: @Rinzwind I think you mean `/etc/resolv.conf`, not `/etc/resolve.conf`

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 does not use /etc/network/interfaces. It uses netplan.

Comment: Follow his ^ advice and ignore me

Comment: how can i use netplan. found manual which said edit the exisiting netplan-file, but i dont have one

Comment: in all internet-manuals they use the netplan file 50-cloud-init.yaml but i just have 01-ens160.yaml which is empty. in all manuals there is a formattet skelletal structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I suggest that you revert the faulty changes to /etc/network/interfaces. Edit the file so that it contains only:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Next, rename your existing empty file:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/01-ens160.yaml /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

Next, edit the file to include your required details. I suggest:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
    enp0s8
      dhcp4: true
```

Netplan is very specific about spacing and indentation. Proofread carefully twice. Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Example yaml files are conveniently located in /usr/share/doc/netplan/examples.

Reboot.

Comment: I followed exactly your advice and now i can ping Websites, but when I start my Server the Message: 
"Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings appears. Is there anything" & my SSH-Connection doesnt work too.

Comment: Do both ethernet ports have an active, working connection, or just one. We ought to remove the lines for the inactive interface. How do you ssh to a DHCP server? Or shall I amend my answer to propse a static IP?

Comment: God bless you man, internet is working now!

I try to connect via SSH with MobaXTerm to the enp0s3-IP shown when i type "ip addr" it Says: 192.168.77.3/24 brd 192.168.77.255. I connected yesterday with 192.168.77.3 and it worked. And today he says: "no connection"

Comment: Since the address is dynamic, is it perhaps no longer xx.3. Check: `ip addr show`

Comment: It's as describes above: the enp0s3 -ip is 192.168.77.3/24. But no connection via SSH to this IP.

Comment: Does MobaXTerm expect to see the full 192.168.77.3/24 or did you try, simply, 192.168.77.3?

Comment: Simply tried 192.168.77.3, when i try with /24 i instantly get notification that there is no available connection: "Host does not exist"

Comment: Problem solved. My Host-Only-Adapter was on wrong IP. chili555 thank you so much for your help!